# Exception of type 'Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.SftpException' was thrown

Tags: c#, sftp, sharpssh

Im able to connect to the sftp server
am able to get the list of files in "pickup" directory.
But I can't download any of those files. 
Here is my code:

```
try
{
    sftp.Get(txtRemotePath.Text + txtFixedFileName.Text, txtLocalPath.Text + txtFixedFileName.Text);
    //example:
    //txtRemotePath.Text + txtFixedFileName.Text = "/pickup/temp.txt";
    //txtLocalPath.Text + txtFixedFileName.Text = @"C:\Users\...\temp.txt"
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    lblError.Text += "\n" + ex.Message;
}
```

I tried modifiying the local and remote paths switching betwen slashes "/" and back-slashes "\", removing/addding starting slashes in remote path..
unfortunatly same error is generated:

Exception of type 'Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.SftpException' was thrown

Comment: Check what the exception `Message` says.

Comment: it says: Exception of type 'Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.SftpException' was thrown 
only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the sftp server security to allow you in through specific port

Answer (score 1):

It was The sftp server security that didn't allow me to download files!

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error when uploading a file. I realised though that I did not have permission to the root directory. When using a folder with the correct permissions I could upload the file successfully.